# Django-Ecommerce 2013

Tags: django

I am a django newbie.I am looking for a framework to develop a simple e-commerce site. I have reviewed other posts but all of the questions and answers looks a bit old.Please suggest a good framework that is simple to use and reliable.Is django-shop a good one ?

Answer (score 6):

[Django Packages](http://www.djangopackages.com) has a pretty comprehensive list of Django apps you can install belonging to different categories and with some detailed description and comparison, here is the [eCommerce](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/ecommerce/) category list.

You can infer that a certain project is actively developed by checking the number of commits it has and how recent they are. Also make sure to check its compatible with Django 1.5 or at least 1.4